# RestAssured JsonPath: Issue with getting list from json

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Can someone who familiar with jsonPath give me an advice how can i get a list of title from each item0, item1, item2 etc.

This query will return

```
findAll {it.key.startsWith('item')}
```

List of maps where key is item and value is body of item object and i don't know how to get List of titles

```
{
   "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
   "item0":{
      "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
      "tabType":"regular",
      "uniqueId":927,
      "hide":"no",
      "title":"title 0",
      "locales":[
         "Locale:en_us",
         "Locale:fr_ca",
         "Locale:es",
         "Locale:pt"
      ],
      "cq:tags":[
         "tag0"
      ]
   },
   "item1":{
      "jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured",
      "tabType":"regular",
      "uniqueId":445,
      "hide":"no",
      "title":"title 1",
      "locales":[
         "Locale:en_us",
         "Locale:fr_ca",
         "Locale:pt",
         "Locale:es"
      ],
      "cq:tags":[
         "Tag1"
      ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution for my question.

```
.items*.find {it.key.startsWith('item')}.value
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is a bit awkward but here's one way to do it:

```
findAll {it.key.startsWith('item')}*.getValue().title
```

Explanation:

First we find all *entries* whose keys starts with "item". For each entry we get its value (using the [spread operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_spread_operator)) and then get title.

Comment: please mark this as the correct answer for your question if it works :)